# Template Reference Variable in AngularJS

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I created a form in angular 13 and include a input filed like in below.

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="_name" #_name="ngModel" required>
</form>
```

then it gives a error like this,

> Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "_name". Template variables strong text are read-only.

however I change the template reference variable **#_name to #name** error is gone. can anyone helop me to find the reason for that?